# How to update a record in mongo db using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created a simple signup and login using node js and mongoDb. I can successfully do signup and login and now I want to add some more data to the user model after logging in from the secret page. How can I do that?

This is my user model and I want to add some text to `user.text` field after loggin in:

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");

    var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: String, 
        password: String,
        text:String
        
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

This is my view page (i.e., the secret page)

```
<h1>Hi, <%= user.username %></h1>
<form action="/birthday" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text">
<button type="submit">Update database</button>
</form>
```

**The text should be shown here after updating**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an API on the node process to send the data to. I suggest you take a look at stuff like Express.js and google about REST API:s.

Comment: Thank you. I learned about the Api's and did it!

Comment: @TanYa Congratz :D If you want to learn more I suggest this course: https://fullstackopen.com/en/ It's free, open-source and really good